# How to befriend one instantiation of template class with other one of the same template

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I have a template class, that uses template parameter only for user interface functions, and internally saves data in some field like `i` in the example. The type of `i` is not templated. All instantiations must work together and access `i`, but `i` must not be accessible externally from template's user.
The problem is how to make friends the different instantiations of the same template. They must access to private data of other instantiations, and internally all those instantiations is the same thing.

Suppose, I want to compare different instantiations of the template like in the example below. Here `i` for instantiation with other template parameter is private, and if I try to declare this template `friend`, it doesn't work.
I know, I can do definition of `operator ==` outside of the class template, but suppose I need to do some function, like `is_same`, that must be a member and I want it's body to be inside of the class declaration.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class C
{
    template<typename U> // ????????
    friend class C;

    template<typename U>
    friend bool operator == (C const& c1, C<U> const& c2) noexcept
    {
      return c1.i == c2.i;
    }

    int i;

  public:

    C(): i {0} {}
    C(int val): i {val} {}

    template<typename U>
    bool is_same(C<U> const& c)
    {
      return c.i == i;
    }

}; // template class C

int main()
{
  C<int>  c1 {5};
  C<char> c2 {5};

  if (c1 == c2) std::cout << "All ok" << std::endl;
  else          std::cout << "Very bad" << std::endl;

  if (c1.is_same(c2)) std::cout << "All ok" << std::endl;
  else                std::cout << "Very bad" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation error (gcc 5.1 -std=c++14)

```
~/main.cpp:15:9: error: «int C<char>::i» is private
```

Comment: Didn't you ask the same very recently?

Comment: Nice job, you've found a Clang bug AFAICS.

Comment: After all, it looks like you're asking for a XY problem. Could you elaborate on your actual use case that needs this please.

Comment: Friendship is not transitive. Your op== is a friend of C<int>, but your op== accesses C<char>::i which is private. It doesn't matter that C<char> is a friend of C<int> for op==.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  I need it to be really answered and not just spamed and minused.

Comment: I didn't downvote your question, but it really seems to be a XY problem as stated. I just asked you to make your question clearer, and elaborate on the real world use case where you actually need this stuff.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub it is not transitive, but it will be instantiated for both friends and all must be ok. It works. You can try it with public i to see. When you declare friends members body inside the class declaration you can't do it for two instantiations that differ from the current. One must be current as I have done above. If you don't trust me just try in real code.

Comment: Why you need friend? you can define operator== as member function, and this code compiles fine.

Comment: @user1034749  It will not compile at all with friend definition and without. If I could compile it I don't asked

Comment: Your carrier as stackoverflow master-asker won't be too sucessful if you can't trust people who understand what's going on and comment on your code.

Comment: I move template<typename U>
    bool operator == (C<U> const& c2) const noexcept
    {
      return i == c2.i;
    } to public section and all compiles fine with gcc 5.2/clang 3.7

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ As I said, the template parameter is needed to do a user interface. It is a refernce to traits class. The code must work as the C is not template at all. Template parameter used from some member functions to know how to do conversions of arguments

Comment: @Johannes Schaub I see your answers but they doesn't help me

Comment: @user1034749 No it doesn't compile with operator in public section. And it is not operator in private section, it is a friend function, it just have definition inside the class

Comment: This code compiles fine http://pastebin.com/m1vFuPDW if it is not for you, may be gcc 5.1 contains bug that was fixed in 5.2, just update compiler

Comment: @user1034749 as I said I can declare operator == even as external function, but it is impossible with other members and doesn't solve the all problem.

Comment: @user1034749 GCC 5.1 compiles this too: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/g8bcjrncGzqn7EnO

Comment: @user1034749 Yes it works. It is not operator for two operands, but I can declare any operator of two operands outside the template. And it works for other functions. Thanks

Comment: But can you give example of operator that must be friend, not member function?

Comment: @user1034749  I can declare in the body something like: `template<typename T1, typename T2> friend bool operator == () (C<T1> const&, C<T2> const&)` and outside the class definition `template<typename T1, typename T2> inline bool operator == ()...` and so on, and it will work with private members. Or I can define all in class declaration, but in that case one operand, the first or the second must be just a C, not templated. In your case operator is not a friend function, it is a member, the value at the right == must be *this

Comment: @user1034749 sorry, at the left of == must be *this

Comment: @Johannes Schaub may be you are right, but I just don't understand, why declaring friend operator works, if body of operator is defined outside of the class, and doesn't work if body is in the class. What I was doing with that sintaxis  - is just a try to avoid to write inline operator outside the class. And I do so in many cases and it usually works

Comment: @user1034749 That is a version with in class definition https://gist.github.com/romikforest/e5994ec20a0eb25e0399

Comment: @user1034749 And that is otisde class https://gist.github.com/romikforest/5554db6596319867026c I always was thinking they are equivalent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So why this not compiled with inside of class,
and compiled outside of class.

When you have this:

```
  template <typename T> struct C { 
  template<typename U>
  friend bool operator == (C const& c1, C<U> const& c2)
  {
    return c1.i == c2.i;
  }
  };
  C<int>() == C<char>()
```

two `::operator==` was generated in outside scope of `class C`, in our case in global namespace: `::operator==<char>(C<int> const& c1, C<char> const& c2)`(1) and
`::operator==<int>(C<char> const& c1, C<int> const& c2)`(2), the first one is friend of `C<int>` and the second one is friend `C<char>`. And compiler uses (1). (1) is only friend of `C<int>` so compile time error.

But if you write code like this:

```
template <typename T> struct C { 
    template<typename U1, typename U>
    friend bool operator == (C<U1> const& c1, C<U> const& c2);
private:
    int i;
};

template<typename U1, typename U>
bool operator == (C<U1> const& c1, C<U> const& c2)
{
    return c1.i == c2.i;
}
```

where `operator==` not implemented inside `C`, then compiler not generate `operator==` outside of scope of class `C` it uses already existing,
so we have `::operator==<int, char>` which friend of both classes `C<int>` and `C<char>`. And at last when you have:

```
template <typename T> struct C { 
    template<typename U1, typename U>
    friend bool operator == (C<U1> const& c1, C<U> const& c2) {
        return c1.i == c2.i;
    }
private:
    int i;
};
```

in case of `C<int>() == C<char>()` you have two generated by compiler variant of `::operator==` `::operator==<int>(C<int>const&, C<char>const&)` and
`::operator==<char>(C<int>const&, C<char>const&)` and compiler should generate a compile time error here.

Reference c++11 standard last draft, sections 14.5.4 and 11.3.5.